# Android PreferenceFragment Get Result From Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, preferences

I have created a `PreferenceFragment` that loads an `xml` file. Within the `xml` is an `intent` item that starts the image picker. The `intent` is as follows:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Your Details">

    <Preference android:title="Your picture" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.PICK"
            android:mimeType="image/*"
            />
    </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

This works fine at displaying the picker and allowing me to make a choice and then return to the settings.

My problem is - how do I find out which image (if any) was chosen?

All the examples I have found so far only seem to demonstrate the `intent` being used to view something. Is it actually possible to get a result using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't create the intent with the xml so I used the event listener to launch the Picker. Here is my code:

```
public class AccountFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

    static final int PICK_AVATAR_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    static final String AVATAR_KEY = "avatar_key";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.account_preferences);

        Preference avatar = findPreference(AVATAR_KEY);
        avatar.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        if(preference.getKey().equals(AVATAR_KEY)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_AVATAR_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_AVATAR_REQUEST_CODE){
            /**
             * You have to call the getData or getDataString to get the images address
             */
            Log.i("CCC", data.getDataString());
        }
    }
}
```

But also when you are creating the xml the documentation tells the answer:

[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: This works fine, even without the `xml` line: `<intent android:action="android.intent.action.PICK"></intent>`. All that is needed is the `title` and `key`. But I am still not sure what use the `xml` `intent` is.

Comment: @ChrisRead you said:  **how do I find out which image (if any) was chosen?** with my solution you can get the address of the images selected. What else do you need?